# Passing parameters between javascript asynchronous callback functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, firefox-addon, mozilla, gecko

I want to use the execAsync function here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Storage#Asynchronously

and I want to pass values between handleResult and handleCompletion. Something like

```
statement.executeAsync({
  handleResult: function(aResultSet) {
    VALUE = 1
  },

  handleCompletion: function(aReason) {
    print(VALUE);
  }
});
```

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

```
var value;

statement.executeAsync({
  handleResult : function(aResultSet) {
    value = 1;
  },
  handleCompletion : function(aReason) {
    print(value);
  }
});
```

Comment: ya I tried that, it doesn't work... 
so the function gets executed multiple times in a short period, I want it to run some code only once, I'm doing that by setting a global flag, but it's not working

Comment: I have something like this:
`var value=0;

statement.executeAsync({
  handleResult : function(aResultSet) {
    value = 1;
  },
  handleCompletion : function(aReason) {
    if(!value) do_something();
  }
});`

Comment: @Tony Have you tried `alert`-ing or `console.log`-ging the `value` to see if and when it actually changes?

Comment: deceze's way is the most obvious and idiomatic way of accomplishing what you ask. You should install firebug and set a few breakpoints to get a feel for what is really going on. I don't see how the pattern that deceze has provided would lead to any errors.

Comment: nvm, I found the problem. Apparently the old version of the function was running at the same time... and it was somehow changing that variable value.

Answer (score 0):

Well the obvious thing to notice is that you're passing an object to executeAsync. (In particular, it's a mozIStorageStatementCallback, so it should have a handleError method too.) So you can easily associate properties specific to that object with the object, using the "this" keyword:

```
statement.executeAsync({
  value: 1,
  handleResult: function(aResultSet) {
    this.value = 0;
  },
  handleError: function(aError) {
    this.value = 2;
  },
  handleCompletion: function(aReason) {
    print(this.value);
  }
});
```